Not able to call Xamarin forms method from CPP code
HI All we are trying to print a tots message from CPP code. The interface and implementation is there in Xamarin forms code. Can any one help us on this please
EX: Interface: IAppSettings
Method : SetupSoftPay();
It displays : "Start SoftPay Settup"
We need to call SetupSoftPay() from CPP code
Any help to achieve to communicate xamarin forms methods from cpp code
